# What is the space used by Scene.ray_cast()?

Tags: scripting

This is the complete 2.8 documentation for `Scene.ray_cast`

> **ray_cast** (view_layer, origin, direction, distance=1.70141e+38)
>
> Cast a ray onto in object space
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> view_layer (ViewLayer, (never None)) – Scene Layer
>
> distance (float in [0, inf], (optional)) – Maximum distance
>
> **Return:** (result, location, normal, index, object, matrix):
>
> result, boolean
>
> location, The hit location of this ray cast, float array of 3 items in
>   [-inf, inf]
>
> normal, The face normal at the ray cast hit location, float array of 3
>   items in [-inf, inf]
>
> index, The face index, -1 when original data isn’t available, int in
>   [-inf, inf]
>
> object, Ray cast object, Object
>
> matrix, Matrix, float multi-dimensional array of 4 * 4 items in [-inf,
>   inf]

Can someone flesh this out for me?

- "Cast a ray into object space": which object?
- Which object's space are `origin` and `direction` in? And the
  returned `location`?
- What is the `matrix`?

Do these all belong to the 'target' object? How would I know what that was before hitting it?

Comment: Without testing so won't answer, pretty sure all values here are globals. (including the face normal as a global)  The matrix being the hit object's matrix_world.

Comment: @batFINGER.. not sure ... why would the docs say 'into object space'? I was hoping to avoid testing. when  I've done it, I'll let you know..

Comment: Lazy docs.  Could argue  it is the "scene objects space".

Comment: @batFINGER, Thanks, you're right as usual. It may seem lazy of _me_ not to test it.. but a beginner has to reverse-engineer an awful lot of the API: it gets to be quite time-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

@ batFINGER was correct in his commentary.. All vectors are in World Space,  the matrix, the hit object's matrix_world.